# How to capture repeated group up to N times?

Tags: c++, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I would like to capture chains of digits in a string, but only up to 3 times.

Any chain of digits afterwards should be ignored. For instance:

`T441_S45/1 => 441 45 1
007_S4 => 007 4
41_445T02_74 => 41 445 02`

I've tried `(\d+){1,3}` but that doesn't seem to work...

Any hint?

Comment: Extract all matches and get the first three.

Comment: That's possible too but that's  not my question as this is then post-processing done after the regex matching and not within.

Comment: Try replacing `^\D*(\d+)(?:\D+(\d+))?(?:\D+(\d+))?.*` with `$1 $2 $3`

Comment: Impressive. Seems to do the job indeed. Why not posting this as an answer instead?

Comment: What is the programming language? I can give a better answer with that detail in mind.

Comment: C++. (What a beautiful monster, gotta study this one on regex101 for a while now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match and capture the first three chunks of digits separated with any amount of non-digits and the rest of the string, and replace with the backreferences to those groups:

```
^\D*(\d+)(?:\D+(\d+))?(?:\D+(\d+))?.*
```

Or, if the string can be multiline,

```
^\D*(\d+)(?:\D+(\d+))?(?:\D+(\d+))?[\s\S]*
```

The replacement string will look like `$1 $2 $3`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digits
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?:\D+(\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching:

  - `\D+` - 1+ non-digits
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `(?:\D+(\d+))?` - another optional non-capturing group matching:

  - `\D+` - one or more non-digits
  - `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `[\s\S]*` - the rest of the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1YhaH1/1).

[C++ demo](https://ideone.com/cMbV8N):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back("T441_S45/1");
    strings.push_back("007_S4");
    strings.push_back("41_445T02_74");

    std::regex reg(R"(^\D*(\d+)(?:\D+(\d+))?(?:\D+(\d+))?[\s\S]*)");
    for (size_t k = 0; k < strings.size(); k++)
    {
        std::cout << "Input string: " << strings[k] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Replace result: " 
                     << std::regex_replace(strings[k], reg, "$1 $2 $3") << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input string: T441_S45/1
Replace result: 441 45 1
Input string: 007_S4
Replace result: 007 4 
Input string: 41_445T02_74
Replace result: 41 445 02
```